# Querying folder with X headers MS Exchange

Tags: soap, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I want to query my email folders for specific emails with custom headers that i've written on them. But it seems like the SOAP message that i am creating have some problems, it always retuns empty result set.

I am sure that i have the email in the folder. If i query after removing the restrictions part, i can see the email in the query results. And if i connect to my account with let's say Thunderbird, then i can see the header is there.

I've searched for at least a week by now, and the only result that i could find is, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/8db4b750-d92f-489b-8282-d109d33314ff/using-finditem-request-to-find-the-items-with-given-header-value, which in the end just tells me my implementation should work.

Thanks for reading.

**QUERY**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010"/>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <FindItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" Traversal="Shallow">
      <ItemShape>
<t:BaseShape>Default</t:BaseShape>
      </ItemShape>
      <m:Restriction>
<t:IsEqualTo>
  <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="InternetHeaders" PropertyName="X-My-Header" PropertyType="String"/>
  <t:FieldURIOrConstant>
    <t:Constant Value="44A2F930-5E24-4F18-BC82-EC6B3A02E893"/>
  </t:FieldURIOrConstant>
</t:IsEqualTo>
      </m:Restriction>
      <m:ParentFolderIds>
<t:FolderId Id="AQMkADAwATM0MDAAMS1jMzg1LWZkMDMtMDACLTAwCgAuAAADlxvq+JrhgkiMcRwVFQDzo9MBANxoXUHEHORLhWKXuo92RaUAAAIBDwAAAA=="/>
      </m:ParentFolderIds>
    </FindItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**RESPONSE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <h:ServerVersionInfo xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="20" MajorBuildNumber="178" MinorBuildNumber="14" Version="V2017_07_11"/>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <m:FindItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
<m:ResponseMessages>
  <m:FindItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
    <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
    <m:RootFolder TotalItemsInView="0" IncludesLastItemInRange="true">
      <t:Items/>
    </m:RootFolder>
  </m:FindItemResponseMessage>
</m:ResponseMessages>
    </m:FindItemResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

If I also try to query the server with AllProperties base shape and my header added to extendedfielduri's, then i get my header in response.

**QUERY**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010"/>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
      <ItemShape>
<t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>
<t:AdditionalProperties>
  <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="InternetHeaders" PropertyName="X-My-Header" PropertyType="String"/>
</t:AdditionalProperties>
      </ItemShape>
      <ItemIds>
<t:ItemId Id="AQMkADAwATM0MDAAMS1jMzg1LWZkMDMtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADlxvq+JrhgkiMcRwVFQDzo9MHANxoXUHEHORLhWKXuo92RaUAAAIBDwAAANxoXUHEHORLhWKXuo92RaUAAS8MrxcAAAA="/>
      </ItemIds>
    </GetItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**RESPONSE(Partial)**

```
<t:DateTimeReceived>2017-10-25T07:55:56Z</t:DateTimeReceived>
<t:Size>11803</t:Size>
<t:Importance>Normal</t:Importance>
<t:IsSubmitted>false</t:IsSubmitted>
<t:IsDraft>true</t:IsDraft>
<t:IsFromMe>false</t:IsFromMe>
<t:IsResend>false</t:IsResend>
<t:IsUnmodified>false</t:IsUnmodified>
<t:InternetMessageHeaders>
  <t:InternetMessageHeader HeaderName="Subject">Test</t:InternetMessageHeader>
  <t:InternetMessageHeader HeaderName="Mime-Version">1.0 (Mac OS X Mail 11.0 \(3445.1.7\))</t:InternetMessageHeader>
  <t:InternetMessageHeader HeaderName="Content-Type">text/html</t:InternetMessageHeader>
  <t:InternetMessageHeader HeaderName="X-Apple-Base-Url">x-msg://1/</t:InternetMessageHeader>
  <t:InternetMessageHeader HeaderName="X-Universally-Unique-Identifier">44A2F930-5E24-4F18-BC82-EC6B3A02E893</t:InternetMessageHeader>
  <t:InternetMessageHeader HeaderName="X-Apple-Mail-Remote-Attachments">YES</t:InternetMessageHeader>
  <t:InternetMessageHeader HeaderName="X-Apple-Windows-Friendly">1</t:InternetMessageHeader>
  <t:InternetMessageHeader HeaderName="Date">Wed, 25 Oct 2017 09:55:56 +0200</t:InternetMessageHeader>
  <t:InternetMessageHeader HeaderName="X-My-Header">44A2F930-5E24-4F18-BC82-EC6B3A02E893</t:InternetMessageHeader>
  <t:InternetMessageHeader HeaderName="Content-Transfer-Encoding">quoted-printable</t:InternetMessageHeader>
  <t:InternetMessageHeader HeaderName="Message-Id">&lt;70916417-FF2F-4FA7-B98E-D0E3E6E91B71@outlook.com&gt;</t:InternetMessageHeader>
  <t:InternetMessageHeader HeaderName="X-Uniform-Type-Identifier">com.apple.mail-draft</t:InternetMessageHeader>
</t:InternetMessageHeaders>
<t:DateTimeSent>2017-10-25T07:55:56Z</t:DateTimeSent>
<t:DateTimeCreated>2017-10-25T07:55:56Z</t:DateTimeCreated>
<t:ResponseObjects>
  <t:ForwardItem/>
```

After this I also tried to see if adding the same parameters to my query will work or not. But no luck. The following query returned exactly the same response as the first one.

**QUERY**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010"/>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <FindItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" Traversal="Shallow">
      <ItemShape>
<t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>
<t:AdditionalProperties>
  <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="InternetHeaders" PropertyName="X-My-Header" PropertyType="String"/>
</t:AdditionalProperties>
      </ItemShape>
      <m:Restriction>
<t:IsEqualTo>
  <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="InternetHeaders" PropertyName="X-My-Header" PropertyType="String"/>
  <t:FieldURIOrConstant>
    <t:Constant Value="44A2F930-5E24-4F18-BC82-EC6B3A02E893"/>
  </t:FieldURIOrConstant>
</t:IsEqualTo>
      </m:Restriction>
      <m:ParentFolderIds>
<t:FolderId Id="AQMkADAwATM0MDAAMS1jMzg1LWZkMDMtMDACLTAwCgAuAAADlxvq+JrhgkiMcRwVFQDzo9MBANxoXUHEHORLhWKXuo92RaUAAAIBDwAAAA=="/>
      </m:ParentFolderIds>
    </FindItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2):

All Internet Headers should be plain strings so in your code

```
<t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="InternetHeaders" PropertyName="X-My-Header" PropertyType="StringArray"/>
```

would need to be

Also I would suggest you just start by trying to see if EWS will return you Header as an additional property eg

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010"/>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <FindItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" Traversal="Shallow">
      <ItemShape>
<t:BaseShape>Default</t:BaseShape>
  <t:AdditionalProperties>
           <t:ExtendedFieldURI DistinguishedPropertySetId="InternetHeaders" PropertyName="X-My-Header" PropertyType="String"/>
          </t:AdditionalProperties>
      </ItemShape>
      <m:ParentFolderIds>
<t:FolderId Id="AQMkADAwATM0MDAAMS1jMzg1LWZkMDMtMDACLTAwCgAuAAADlxvq+JrhgkiMcRwVFQDzo9MBANxoXUHEHORLhWKXuo92RaUAAAIBDwAAAA=="/>
      </m:ParentFolderIds>
    </FindItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

If you don't see your property returned with the Item then a Restriction won't work. Generally with X-Headers they need to provisioned https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn596091(v=exchg.150).aspx you should then see them as a separate Extended property when you look at the Item with a Mapi Editor like MFCMapi or OutlookSpy.

Comment: Sorry that i copied the code from my trials, I was trying every option available for PropertyType, but no luck. I will test if the value is returned when i query the email itself.

Comment: I've updated the question with your suggestions. Sadly, the problem is still there.

Comment: Did you try provisioning the header using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn596091(v=exchg.150).aspx ? it should then work on any new messages received with that Header (eg after that the header is mapped to a named property and will be available as an additional property in the message)